# Rails Form Select Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to not accept a `<option value="">Select one</option>` in my Rails form.

This is my code:

```
<div class="field">
    <p><%= f.label :category, "Category:" %></p>
    <%= f.select(:category, [["-- Select One --", "false"],'Analytics','Commerce','Content Management','Gaming','Green','Media','Social Media','Technology - Software','Technology - Hardware', 'Web']) %>
</div>
```

With JQuery Validation plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name='commit']").click(function(){
    $("#new_startup").validate({
      rules: { startup[category]: { valueNotEquals: "false" } },
      messages: { startup[category]: { valueNotEquals: "Please select one" } } 
    });
    if ($("#new_startup").valid())
      location.href = "#";
      $("#tag").css("display","none");
      $("#thank-you").css("display","block");
  });
});
```

This doesn't work though... is there a better method?

Setting `["-- Select One --", ""]` didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want either a `prompt` or an `include_blank` in your select.

`<%= f.select(:category, ['Analytics','Commerce','Content Management','Gaming','Green','Media','Social Media','Technology - Software','Technology - Hardware', 'Web'], :include_blank => '-- Select One --') %>`

See the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) for more.